# Add parameter to URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have two domain names mydomain.aaa and mydomain.bbb pointing to the same place.
What I would like to do is tell index.php using parameters through which domain I am accessing it.

eg

```
www.mysite.bbb/folder/?param1=23&param2=34
```

would become

```
www.mysite.aaa/folder/?param1=23&param2=34&lang=bbb
```

and

```
www.mysite.bbb/folder/
```

would become

```
www.mysite.aaa/folder/?lang=bbb
```

how to achieve this using .htaccess

I am using external hosting so I do not have access to the apache config file.

Comment: Why is there `;` instead of `&`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.bbb$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.aaa%{REQUEST_URI}?lang=bbb [R=302,NE,L]
```